# Why can't I really follow this Android Studio tutorial?

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBD4xhH5vIE) on how to use Android Studio to create android apps. At the very end, the user opens the file 'build.gradle' which looks completely different from what I have:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 

all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Maybe this is not very important? Or is the video using an old version of AndroidStudio/SDK/gradle/whatever?

Comment: Try opening the other build.gradle file.

Comment: *is the video using an old version of AndroidStudio* correct, a **very** old version in fact. since may 30 2014 android studio went from beta version 0.8 or something, to fully operational 1.4

Comment: Ah found it elsewhere, thanks. Developing something for android is really extremely complicated. I guess it will take me months to create the first app...

Comment: The half-life of Android educational resources is about a year, IMHO. IOW, the value of some resource is halved a year after its last update, is worth 25% of its original two years out, etc. That particular tutorial is ~16 months old at this point, which means you will need to take a grain of salt with some of the stuff presented there.

Comment: "Developing something for android is really extremely complicated." - it is only as complicated as you want make it, with a couple of days or maybe weeks of basic training you can already create some pretty cool apps

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the *top-level* gradle file. The gradle file that appears in the video is the `app` module one.

You can have more than one module in the same project to divide your app code and/or to create different apps that share some code. Each module has its own gradle file to configure its dependencies and know how to compile it. The top-level file contains common configuration options for all modules, as the top comment tells.